# Adobe Indesign: Forms: Set critera/validation of form fields

Tags: pdf, forms, adobe-indesign

I am running Adobe InDesign 19.0.1 x64.
I am creating a fillable form and would like to include validation on some of the fields. For example when the user is asked for ID# I would like to have the form field limited to 8 characters that are all numbers.
In the email address field, I would like to block symbols and the @ sign as they are only being asked to enter the part before the @.
In the Date field, make sure they are entering a proper date that is not in the future.

While I can figure out how to make the fields required, I cannot seem to find how to do validation. Any guidance would be appreciated.